# Determine the total number of candlesticks from the first index

Tags: pine-script

How to get the total number of candles when processing the first bar?
I used the following code for this purpose and it works well for the crypto currency market which is active 24 hours a day and seven days a week, but it does not work well in the stock market (time_close returns the closing time of the session)

```
interval := na(interval) ? time_close - time : interval
totalBar := na(totalBar) ? int((timenow - time) / interval) + 1 : totalBar
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accurately determine the total number of bars in the dataset on the first bar, because there's no way to account for holidays and other days the markets are closed and/or trade less hours than usual due to early close (like Christmas Eve for example). Trading halts will also influence (reduce) the number of bars, as will thinly traded periods where for example only 1 trade was done in 3 hours (you don't get 3 hourly bars for that).

Comment: an approximate calculation is sufficient.